# NgbModal generic service

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to be able to show forms in a modal or on the page.  My forms on pages are pretty straight forward because both the page and form exist in the same module.  However, for forms in modals, things are a bit different.

I want to create a generic service that I can call and pass in a component to have that component show up in a modal.  So my service has a method like this:

```
showForm(component: any, options?:NgbModalOptions){
    const modal = this.ngbModal.open(content, {
      backdrop: 'static',
      size: 'lg',
     ...options
   });
   ...
}
```

This modal service was going to be in my SharedModule which is imported at the appmodule level.  I then have a secure module that is lazy loaded.  In the secure module I have a PracticeFormComponent that is the form that I want to show in my modal.  I have PracticeFormComponent in declarations, exports and entryComponents of the SecureModule.

When I try to call modalService.showForm(PracticeFormComponent) from a page that is also declared in SecureModule, I get an error saying that No component factory is found.  I'm not sure what I am missing here.

If anybody can help me with that and also a second question of would it be possible to call a FormComponent to load from another module even if it's lazy loaded child or sibling of the SecureModule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I then have a secure module that is lazy loaded. In the secure module I have a PracticeFormComponent that is the form that I want to show in my modal.

The `PracticeFormComponent` component factory does not exist until the lazy module is loaded.

> When I try to call modalService.showForm(PracticeFormComponent) from a page that is also declared in SecureModule

You're using the component class (the constructor function) instead of the component factory. WebPack will allow you to **import** this function directly from the TypeScript file. So there won't be any compile time errors, but at run-time the modal services will try to discover the component factory from this reference, and it's going to be using the dependency injector that was used to create that server.

You need to change your `showForm()` function so that it requires a component factory instead of an `any`, and use that to create the modal.

This will then help you resolve the module related dependency issues, because you'll be unable to get the factory unless it exists in the DI.

You can create modals from inside the lazy module, but not from outside of it. If you need to do this outside the lazy module, then that modal component isn't really lazy. It's a shared component.